Baby Rudin Chapter 7 Exercise 9
The problem is

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions which converges uniformly to a function $f$ on a set $E$. Prove that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x_n) = f(x)$
for every sequence of points $x_n \in E$ such that $x_n \to x$, and $x \in E$. Is the converse of this true?

I've been able to prove the first section, but I'm having trouble coming up with a basic counterexample to show the converse is not true. Any tips/suggestions?

Here's a counterexample. Let $E = (0,1)$ and let $f_n:E \to \Bbb R$ be given by $f_n(x) = x^n$. Note that $\{f_n\}$ does not converge uniformly, but it has pointwise limit $f(x) = 0$.
However, $\{f_n\}$ does converge to $f$ uniformly over the restricted domain $[0,a]$ for any $0<a<1$. Thus, for any sequence $x_n$ converging to $x \in E$, we have $x_n \in [0,\frac{x + 1}{2}]$ for all but finitely many $n$, which means that we can apply the first part of the problem to the $f_n$ restricted to the interval $[0, \frac{x+1}{2}]$ and deduce that $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Note 1: For another counterexample, let $E = \Bbb R$, and let $f_n : E \to \Bbb R$ be given by
$
f_n(x) = \frac{n+1}{n}x
$.
Note that $E$ is closed, but not bounded.
Note 2: the converse does hold if we impose the constraint that $E$ is compact.
